# Is there a way to forcefully prompt save-as dialog when saving an excel file in an Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular6, save-as

In my angular 6 project I'm trying to forcefully open the save-as dialog whenever the user tries to download the excel file (I'm using blob). Is there a way to do this without manually changing the browser settings?

Thank you. I appreciate any help.

Comment: if you mean opening the save dialog without user interaction I don't think that browsers allow it without user initiating it

Answer (score 0):

I usually just add a timestamp for the filenames when my users download files.
At least it guarentees that filenames are unique.

To trigger this in Angular, I use this invisible href trick.

```
public onDownloadClick() {
    const filename = `${new Date().toISOString()}.txt`;

    // create invisible download link.
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sgf));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    // click it, and remove it.
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

But it does not really show a "save-as" dialog, it just starts downloading the file straightaway.

If you really want to use the save-as dialog, you'll need to add a dependency to your angular project.

```
npm install file-saver
npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev
```

Next, you can import the dependency in your component.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

public onDownloadClick() {
    const blob = new Blob(...);
    saveAs(blob, 'defaultFilename.xlsx');.
}
```

The github page shows more details about the usage of the `saveAs` function.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer @bvdb. Actually, I've already tried using the file-saver however the download behavior is still dependent on the browser's download settings. I want to always prompt 'save-as' dialog (no matter what is set on the browsers settings)